# Feign jackson cannot decode String with leading 0

Tags: java, json, jackson, feign

I have a feign client with configured `JacksonDencoder` which looks like that:

```java
protected Feign.Builder resilience4JFeignBuilder(
        ObjectMapper objectMapper, ClientProperties props, Class<?> clazz) {
    return Resilience4jFeign.builder(createDefaultDecorators(props))
            .logger(new Slf4jLogger(clazz))
            .logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
            .decoder(new JacksonDecoder(objectMapper))
```

and feign client:

```java
public interface SomeServiceFeignClient {
    @RequestLine(value = "GET somepath/{value}/convert")
    String translate(@Param("value") String value);
}
```

The problem is when endpoint `GET somepath/{value}/convert` returns String with '0' at the begining e.g "0254" then following exception is thrown:

```
feign.FeignException: Invalid numeric value: Leading zeroes not allowed.
```

I know that i can set `objectMapper.enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NUMERIC_LEADING_ZEROS);`property and exception is not thrown but still '0' is removed and "254" is produced.

Is it possible to configure `JacksonEncoder` to handle String return types without removing '0' from the beginning ?

Comment: Why is it trying to convert to a number in the first place? If it is a string, it should remain a string. Do you have an intermediate class to which you convert which has a number type and not a string type for the property?

Comment: No i don't have any intermediate class. It did not convert it to number but it removed '0' at the begining.